# Вывести дочерние страницы WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

Как вывести дочерние страницы конкретной страницы (например по ID), и вывести только заголовок, ссылку и изображение (обложку)?

Comment: В чём именно проблема? Задай вопрос так, чтобы можно было понять задачу.

Comment: @SeVlad а что именно не понятно? Нужно получить дочерние страницы по ID родительской и вывести в таком же виде, как обычно выводятся посты. В сети нашел решение для вывода дочерних страниц по ID или даже названию, но так и не понял, как вывести их заголовок, обложку и ссылку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот такой цикл нужен

```
<?php

$args = [
    'post_type'   => 'page',
    'post_parent' => $parent_id,
];

$query = new WP_Query( $args );

while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    $query->the_post();

    the_title();
    the_permalink();
    the_post_thumbnail();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Параметр post_parent отвечает за это. Так же можно использовать post_parent__in. Подробнее тут: https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_query

```
$args  = [
    'post_parent'    => $parent_ID,
    'post_type'      => 'page',
    'posts_per_page' => 3,
];
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    while( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();
        the_title();
        the_permalink();
        the_post_thumbnail();
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```